# How Do I Install Lua on MacOS?

Tags: macos, lua

I just downloaded Lua from the official website.

I want to install it on my Mac but I have no clue how. And I've never tried using Mac to install and use compilers other then (xcode , titanium , corona) so easy on me please :)

I tried [this link](http://api-meal.eu/memo/143-how-to-install-lua-5-in-mac-os-x-leopard/) but it does not work.

Also Is there a fully guided on how to install and start using Lua on mac? Because all I see is windows :S

note: Before I asked this question I searched on SOV but I could not find my answer.

Comment: When you say you tried that link and it "does not work", you forgot to mention what, precisely, "did not work".  There are about a billion ways (conservatively guessing) for software to "not work".  We need a bit more information than that to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Compiling from source code is not that painful.

Lua 5.1.4 here: http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.1.4.tar.gz
Lua 5.2 alpha here: http://www.lua.org/work/lua-5.2.0-alpha.tar.gz

Take Lua 5.2 as example:

1. Open your Terminal.app
2. wget http://www.lua.org/work/lua-5.3.0-work3.tar.gz
3. tar xvzf lua-5.3.0-work3.tar.gz
4. cd lua-5.3.0-work3/src
5. make macosx(I believe you have Xcode installed)

After that, you can see 'lua' binary under current dir.

```
sudo cp lua /usr/bin/lua
```

Now you can enter lua to have a try. :)

Comment: Thanks so much. After I entered this command sudo cp lua /usr/bin/lua   it asked me for a password. I entered my machine pass but it didn't work. can you help ? :S

Comment: See also http://www.lua.org/faq.html#1.1  Change linux to macosx and after building do `make install`.

Comment: Thanks. I successfully managed to run the compiler. I will get back whenever I have trouble Thanks @lht and @Prajna

Comment: Thanks for this, worked! Anyone who wants to know, the lua file you need to copy is found under your current dir /src/lua

Comment: To make this possible I had to change /usr/bin/lua to /usr/local/bin/lua and it works fine.

Comment: Every guide I've read misses the cp step. its pretty hard to notice that theres a lua bin in there now.

The lua binary was in the src directory for me.

Also you should install to usr/local/bin

Comment: should copy to /usr/local/bin instead of /usr/bin

Comment: I don't see a macosx option in the [makefile](https://github.com/lua/lua/blob/master/makefile)

Answer (score 67):

This Wiki has few listing:
http://lua-users.org/wiki/MacOsxLua

If you use Homebrew (https://brew.sh/), just type:

```
brew update
brew install lua
```

Answer (score 24):

If you have `brew` installed, just try:

`brew install lua`

Answer (score 3):

You just follow this guide on http://www.lua.org/start.html:

Fire up your terminal and type in:

```
curl -R -O http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.3.5.tar.gz
tar zxf lua-5.3.5.tar.gz
cd lua-5.3.5
make macosx test
make install
```

You can even combine the last two steps to

```
make macosx install
```

After that I could just type in

```
lua
```

into my terminal and something like:

```
Lua 5.3.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2018 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
```

should appear. This means that lua is installed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

With [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/):

```
sudo port install lua
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `brew`, use the following code:

```
brew update
brew install lua
```

That works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Compile using source on mac

```
tar -zxvf lua-x.x.x.tar.gz 
cd lua-x.x.x
make macosx
cd src
sudo cp lua /usr/bin/

Type lua and you should get the prompt.
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just follow the Prajna's answer and go to http://www.lua.org/versions.html#5.3 to download the lua-5.3.6.tar.gz

And then use the terminal:

```
$cd lua-5.3.6/src

$make macosx
```

After that, you can see 'lua' binary under current dir.

After execute:

```
$sudo cp lua /usr/bin/lua
```

You can run the lua

Answer (score 0):

You don't "install" it. It should just be a binary that runs from wherever you extract it to.

If you can't find a binary (there should be one linked somewhere on the Lua site) then just follow the instructions to build it from source.

Ah, here are the binaries: http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/download.html

You'll probably want the file labelled "MacOS X Intel Executables"

Answer (score 0):

The download url show below. 
http://www.lua.org/download.html

lua-5.3.1.tar.gz 
2015-06-10, 276K